# HTML5Boilerplate with a Grid system

Tags: grid, html5boilerplate

Is there any standard grid system to use with HTML5Boilerplate. I am thinking of using grid960, are they working well together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Standard, no. But I see more and more people use Bootstrap. Even the same people who previously relied on 960.gs, me included. There is a great variety of plugins available for Bootstrap, LESS support and easy to skin styles makes it a good choice.